# Install-Package : Unable to find package 'JSNLog'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget-package, jsnlog

I am trying to install JSNLog through Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2010 as per the instructions given in http://www.jsnlog.com/Documentation/DownloadInstall but I am getting installation error...as below.

[image]

I am wondering that has something changed with the command ?? and also how can we restore the missing NuGet packages from the project solution -- I updated the NuGet version

Environment I have is

Visual Studio 2010 Professional and NuGet from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

Main Purpose of using JSNLog is to implement client side Logging in my project...

Any thoughts pelase...

Comment: You've got a message there about missing packages - it's a guess, but try restoring them and then try again.

Comment: @dave -- for restore missing NuGet packages -- I updated the setting -- UnChecked -- Allow NuGet to download missing packages during the build -- as shown in this image http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/images/allow-package-restore-configuration.png  --   Coming back to other part -- How can I install the JSNLog ??

Comment: You could also try adding JSNLog via the 'Manage NuGet Packages' dialog in solution explorer to see if that works. Another possibility is that your NuGet config is corrupt. I had a similar issue http://blog.daveclements.co.uk/2012/09/18/nuget-setvalue-cannot-be-called-on-a-nullsettings/